# execute qlmanage in sandboxed (electron) App doesn't work

Tags: macos, shell, electron, appstore-sandbox, quicklook

My setup is an electron app on macOs. I am using [exec-sh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec-sh) to run `$ qlmanage`... to generate thumbnails. It all works fine, except when I sign the app and set the sandbox entitlements to true. I tried everything, but nothing works:

- added com.apple.security.files.user-selected.executable to my plist
- copied the Image.qlgenerator Plugin into my app (in build process) and force the command to use this generator
- set folder permissions (but other commands like mkdir or create/write files are working)
- all combinations of qlmanage options

If I set `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` to `false` it works. The error log is pretty useless to me:

`Error: Shell command exit with non zero code: 255`

I am pretty unsure if it is even possible to run $ `qlmanage` inside a sandboxed app...

Answer (score 0):

To get a Quicklook image from a file, you'd rather use

```
CGImageRef QLThumbnailImageCreate(CFAllocatorRef allocator, CFURLRef url, CGSize maxThumbnailSize, CFDictionaryRef options);
```

This will return an CGImage that you may use as a thumbnail. See documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/1402623-qlthumbnailimagecreate

Comment: @zinne Did this answer help you? If yes, I'd kindly suggest you to mark it as accepted. Thank you